# export images with data from Mysql to excel using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, excel

Am trying to export my data along side images from mysql database using php.
The plain data is successfully exported to excel but the images donot display rather display error "the linked image cannot be displayed.The file may have been moved,renamed or deleted.Verify link points to correct file and location".

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HJ17.png)

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HJ17.png)

```html
<?php
// The function header by sending raw excel
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
 // Defines the name of the export file "codelution-export.xls"
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=system_users.xls");
 // Add data table
include("config/dbconfig.php"); 
?>
<!-- Image path in subfolder images -->
<img src="images/reph.png" height="115" width="730"> 
<table width=70% border="1" class="view"  align="center">

  <tr><th> No</th>
     <th> Name</th>

 <th>User Role</th>
 <th>User Name</th>
 <th>Password</th>

</class> </tr><tr> 
  <?php
$sno=1;
  $query=mysql_query("select * from users ");

  $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
  if($num_rows>0)
  { while ($fields=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {  $sno<=$num_rows; 
   $pid=$fields['user_id'];
   $lname=$fields['lname'];
  ?>
   <td>&nbsp; <?php echo "$sno ";
$sno++; ?></td>
<td>&nbsp; <?php echo $fields['lname']." ".$fields['fname'];?></td>
<td><?php // php code that retrieves image path from the database and prints the image
 //echo '<img width="120" height="110"  SRC="' .$fields['image'] . '" alt="Image failed to load " />'; 
 ?></td>
 <td>&nbsp; <?php echo $fields['role'];?></td>
 <td>&nbsp; <?php echo $fields['username'];?></td>

<td>&nbsp; <?php echo $fields['password'];?></td>
</tr>
  <?php
     }//closing the while loop
    }//closing the if statement
         echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: _The file may have been moved,renamed or deleted_ means  
? From where ? Also include code in your question.

Comment: Thanks Niklesh , i have provided source code in the post , kindly help me guys

Comment: Given that you're just creating html markup rather than a native format Excel file, any image links you include are just that, links.... if you want to save the image itself base64 encoded as data in the src attribute; otherwise, look at creating a real native format Excel file that supports embedded images